# Use match in select query by concat function for fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Why do I get error when run this query?

```
SELECT 
   `site_members`.`username`,
   `site_members`.`email`,
   `site_members`.`ID`,
   `site_members`.`firstName`,
   `site_members`.`lastName`,
   `site_members`.`avatar`,
   `site_members`.`avatar_status`,
   `site_members_privacy`.`searchable_profile`,
   CONCAT(firstName , ' ', lastName ) AS `concat_name`,
   `site_members_privacy`.*
FROM `site_members`
LEFT JOIN 
    `site_members_privacy` 
        ON site_members.ID = site_members_privacy.memberID 
        WHERE (email LIKE '%test%' OR CONCAT(firstName , ' ', lastName ) LIKE '%test%')
        OR (MATCH(concat_name) AGAINST('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
ORDER BY `firstName` ASC, `lastName` ASC, `username` ASC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Y U No give us error?

Comment: I give: Mysqli prepare error: Unknown column 'concat_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: and concat didnot work in "like where" condition

Comment: I think you cannot reference the AS name `concat_name` in the statement itself. I believe SQL processes the statement backward from how it's written.

Comment: You error was pretty straight forward. SQL couldn't find the `concat_name` column as that column doesn't exist.

Comment: I know , but I defined concat_name var at field list

Comment: I know, but I think that happens after even though its written first. I believe SQL sort of works from the inside out if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
MATCH(concat_name)
```

to

```
MATCH(CONCAT(firstName , ' ', lastName))
```

This is sort of a guess, but I think you have to do it that way.

Comment: error: Mysqli prepare error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`firstName` , ' ', `lastName` )) AGAINST('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ORDER BY `fi' at line 2

Comment: Are you sure you are using the match against correctly? I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: No idea, I am not familiar with CONCAT but it looks like your syntax is right.

Comment: match didnot work but I use successfully CONCAT(firstName , ' ', lastName ) LIKE '%test%'

Comment: I shoud poke mysql developers :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `MATCH()` works -- you need to provide it with a comma-separated list of fields to search.  Presumably, these would be the fields that you used for your `FULLTEXT` index.